# Using PHP to Replace URL in HTML

Tags: php, html, url

Using PHP I want to remove a whole `<iframe>` element that contains the string `abc.com`

If I were to search the following for abc.com:

```
‹iframe src="http://abc.com/abcd.html"›‹/iframe›

‹iframe src="http://abc.com/lmno.html"›‹/iframe›

‹iframe src="http://xyz.com/wxyz.html"›‹/iframe›
```

I wish to be left with the following text after the first two elements are removed:

```
‹iframe src="http://xyz.com/wxyz.html"›‹/iframe›
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, and [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store you all URLs in a string array and then iterate through them and apply the following test.

```
<?php

    foreach($array_of_urls as $url) {
        if( strpos( $url, 'abc.com' ) !== false ) {
            $url = "";
        }
    }



?>
```

Comment: How does this replace the whole iFrame element?

Comment: @AlexW I'm assuming the developer is writing HTML using PHP echo statements as mostly developers do. Second, It is not about replacement, it is about removal: therefore, I used `$url = "";`. Third, As I wrote, All urls are contained in an array, and after removing the desired ones, the developer can once again split them conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `preg_replace()` :

```
$text = preg_replace('#<iframe src=".*?abc\.com.*?"></iframe>#','',$text);
```